# vaild json output while attaching custom tags

Tags: php, json

my existing php code is giving a vaild json out for this piece of code

```
    echo json_encode($player,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

output

```
{
  "0": {
    "0": "1.g",
    "1": "d4",
    "2": "3.g",
    "3": "8.g",
    "4": "wc",
    "5": "s.b",
    "6": "r.y"
  },
  "7": {
    "0": "9.y",
    "1": "2.g",
    "2": "2.g",
    "3": "5.g",
    "4": "1.y",
    "5": "7.r",
    "6": "3.b"
  }
}
```

where as when i try to use this piece of code for custom tags

```
$player_no=0;
while($player_no<$no_of_players){
    echo json_encode (['Player '.$player_no=>$player[$player_no]],JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    $player_no++;
}
```

it gives a json which is invaild

```
{
    "Player 0": {
        "0": "9.r",
        "1": "4.g",
        "2": "r.g",
        "3": "wc",
        "4": "2.b",
        "5": "5.r",
        "6": "8.g"
    }
}{
    "Player 7": {
        "0": "7.y",
        "1": "6.g",
        "2": "6.y",
        "3": "8.r",
        "4": "5.y",
        "5": "r.y",
        "6": "7.y"
    }
}
```

could let me know why is it invalid and what would be the problems in reading the second code?
what changes do need to make in php server side code for correct valid output with respective to second one

Comment: it would need to be an array to contain 2 objects so No comma between `}` and `{` and no `[]` wrapping the whole lot

Comment: Rule 1: Dont try an build your own JSON Strings, Build a PHP data structure, Object or Array and then use `json_encode()` on that data structure ONCE at the end

Comment: You `echo json_encode()` for every player, should merge them first and then `echo json_encode()` the array of all players

Answer (score 2):

You are actually outputting multiple json strings (one for each loop), instead store the data and output it all after the loop...

```
$player_no=0;
$data = [];
while($player_no<$no_of_players){
    $data['Player '.$player_no] = $player[$player_no];
    $player_no++;
}
echo json_encode($data ,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT))
```

Answer (score 0):

change the second part to this piece of code

```
$player_arrays=array();
    while($player_no<$no_of_players){
        $player_arrays['Player '.$player_no]=$player[$player_no];
        $player_no++;
    }
    echo json_encode($player_arrays,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

then the output will be

```
{
    "Player0": {
        "0": "r.y",
        "1": "d4",
        "2": "4.y",
        "3": "9.r",
        "4": "6.g",
        "5": "0.r",
        "6": "5.b"
    },
    "Player7": {
        "0": "7.y",
        "1": "s.y",
        "2": "2.y",
        "3": "7.b",
        "4": "9.y",
        "5": "0.b",
        "6": "4.b"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first output is an Object, as denoted by `{}` that contains 2 Properties as denoted by `"0":` and `"7":`, each of these 2 properties itself contains an object.

Your second output is just 2 individual Objects, which when received by the javascript (I assume) cannot be processed as a single item as they are 2 very seperate items i.e. 2 unrelated and uncontained objects.